# Local Style sheet not being applied in Print Preview

Tags: css, jsp

I am working with some JSP pages, to which I added a "local" style sheet. By local, I mean relative to the JSP's path and not up further in the web app folder structure.

Now these JSP pages are built using scriptlet code and customer web page object developed internally.

I am able to include my own style sheet as such

```
wp.addCss(page_context + "/abc/include/styles/custom.css");
```

However, when the server renders that JSP to the client, that line above becomes

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
  <!--
    @import url('/app/abc/include/styles/custom.css');
  -->
</style>
```

In this custom.css I then have the following media query section defined

```
@media print {
  button.btn-anchor {
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif !important;
    font-size: 72% !important;
    background: transparent !important;
    border: 0 !important;
  }
}
```

So, basically, I have buttons defined in the JSP with the class name set btn-anchor to make the button look like an anchor tag. However, when the page is printed, those buttons look like buttons. The above will remove the button look.

Now to my issue, that style is not applied in print preview. Using Chrome's developer tools and emulating CSS media print, the buttons look like buttons and inspecting the element, the styles window has no mention of custom.css.

So how do I get this to work? Do I really have to move the styles needed over to the print style sheet we have setup?

Comment: what is `wp.addCss`? This function seems to be outputting `<style type="text/css" media="screen">`. The `media="screen"` is your issue. If you can change that to `all`, you'll be half way there.

Comment: "wp" refers to an internally developed servlet that spits out an empty web page structure. ".addClass" allows for a developer to specify additional CSS files to be added to the head section of the page, along with internally defined standard CSS files. So when the wp servlet renders the html to the client it does the whole media='screen' and media='print'

Comment: Got it. Your solution lies in getting the output of `media` to be explicitly passed by that function, and perhaps fallback to `screen` if unspecified.